# Answer questions to generate word doc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

hoping for some help here -

I’m trying to build something where I can fill in some blanks, select some drop down boxes or something similar to then generate a word doc.
Here’s my scenario - i work for a physician who does procedures on people. After the procedure we sent their doctor a letter saying what we did. So I’d like to initially answer some questions like

1. docs name
2. date of procedure
3. patients name
4. presenting symptoms
5. procedure done.

Etc. and then after answering those questions the answers will appear in the document between some pre-written text.
I’ve tried using ms word fillable forms, but it sort of limits me because I have to protect the document which prevents me from making any minor editing which I occasionally need to do. Also I seem to run into problems because sometimes we only do one procedure and sometimes we do multiple. So I’d need it to automatically say we did x, y, and z. Or just x and y. Or just x….  If that makes sense. Ideally I could just check some boxes of what procedure(s) we did and then they show up in the document after I was done selecting the options

Thanks in advance for any advice and suggestions!

Comment: This would require custom software which won’t be trivial to write

Comment: Did you tried mail merge in MS Word? It allows you to place, placeholders (fields), at appropriate places in the word doc. Data can be extracted from Excel. Its easy to setup when each page is a single page document (so that you can create multiple forms just by using mail merge wizard)